# JPGICC: What does the option described as "Precalculates transform" do?

Tags: color-management, photo-management

The man page of `jpgicc` says `-c NUM Precalculates transform (0=Off, 1=Normal, 2=Hi-res, 3=LoRes) [defaults to 1].`

I was not able to find more information about that option. To me it seems 1 is a trade-off between speed and quality. But to me, speed does not matter.

What does "Hi-res" mean and why should I prefer it over "Normal" (or why should I prefer "Normal" over "Hi-res")?

Answer (score 2):

I must admit I'm not a person that cares much about color accuracy. If colors are different enough between text and background, and I can read the screen, I'm happy.

### 7 year old email chain about precalculations

The differences between no precalculations, normal, low-res and high-res is not just speed but can lead to [flaws in the shadows](https://sourceforge.net/p/lcms/mailman/message/29597867/):

> I had Cinepaint set in the color management options to use "don't
> Precalculate" rather than one of the other Cinepaint options (Low
> Resolution, High Resolution, CMM default). I wish I had realized that
> particular setting might make a difference, because it would have
> saved a lot of time and tedious testing.
>
> I don't know of any image editing program besides Cinepaint that
> offers the user the choice to use Low Res, High Res, CMM default, or
> "Don't Precalculate". I would guess that most or all use something
> like "CMM default", because I just checked, and Cinepaint, when set to
> use "CMM default" and "use black point compensation" produces the same
> halving of the shadow values as all the other image editors.
>
> At any rate, at this point every image editor that I tested, other
> than Cinepaint and the latest Krita 2.6 alpha, produces visibly
> damaged shadow areas if there is a linear gamma profile involved in an
> ICC profile conversion.

---

### littleCMS's Author's take on precalculations

In his [.pdf tutorial](https://www.littlecms.com/LittleCMS2.11%20tutorial.pdf) the author states if there are only a few colors to transform then precalculations can be turned off all together:

> **Optimization**
>
> Little CMS tries to optimize profile chains whatever possible. There are some built-in optimization
> schemes, and you can add new schemas by using a plug-in. This generally improvesthe performance
> of the transform, but may introduce a small delay of 1-2 seconds when creating the transform. If
> you are going to transform just few colors, you don't need this precalculations. Then, the flag
> cmsFLAGS_NOOPTIMIZE in cmsCreateTransform() can be used to inhibit the optimization process.
> See the API reference for a more detailed discussion of the flags.

Comment: Wow, what you are finding in your old email is amazing!

Comment: @abu_bua It's not my email. The developers' emails back and forth to each other are mostly public.